# Extracting intensity from density plot image given color bar

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing, color, image

I have an image showing a density plot from a paper, as well as the corresponding color bar. I am trying to convert this back to a 2D array of intensities.

[image]

[image: 2]

Here's what I did, which works but seems to be imperfect.

```
imagedata = ImageData[plotimage]
colordata = ImageData[colorimage][[row]]
```

where `row` is a number which selects a single row out of the center of the color bar. `imagedata` is a rank 2 array of `{R,G,B}` values, while `colordata` is a rank 1 array of `{R,G,B}` values (between 0 and 1). I assume the color bar goes from 2 to 7. I then sample a number of colors from the bar with equal spacings,

`colorbar = colordata[[1;;-1;;step]]`
for some integer `step` such as `step = Round[Length@colordata/30.]`. Let `ncols = Length@colorbar`, the number of color samples. This looks like

`cols = RGBColor@@#&/@colordata[[2 ;;]]`
[image]

Since the image has a lot of white space which I want to differentiate, I add a single white element as the first element: `colorbar = Prepend[colorbar,{1,1,1}]`.

Now my basic strategy is to get each pixel's `{R,G,B}` (I downsample the image to make this process not take forever because it's rather inefficient) and associate it to a single element of `colorbar`. I don't know the best way to do this, but my strategy right now is to minimize `Norm[{R,G,B}-{R',G',B'}]`, to find the `{R',G',B'}` in `colorbar` which is "closest" by this metric to the color of the pixel, I don't know if this is a good method of color matching though. I define a function

```
f[c_] := Module[{n},
  n = First@First@Position[colordata,#]&@First@MinimalBy[colordata,Norm[c-#]&]-1;
  If[n==0, 0, 2. + 5 n/ncols]
]
```

which takes an `{R,G,B}` vector, uses `MinimalBy` to find the element of `colorbar` for which the `Norm` of the difference is minimal, and returns its index minus one. Since white was the first index, if the result it zero I return `0` while for non-white colors I scale the output between 2 and 5 like the original color scale.

Defining a color function from the sampled colors,

```
colorf[x_] := Blend[cols,(x-2)/5]
```

the plotted result looks like this:

```
imagedataConverted = ParallelTable[
   f[imagedata[[j, i]]],
   {j, 1, Dimensions[imagedata][[1]], 1},
   {i, 1, Dimensions[imagedata][[2]], 1}
];

ListDensityPlot[imagedataConverted,
 ColorFunction -> colorf,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{colorf, {2, 7}}], Above],
 PlotRange -> {2, 7},
 ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

This seems to work, but there are some subtle differences in the output. Overall it seems to me that the output is on average a bit lighter, and especially so near the edges. This is causing me some issues because I want the match to be as close as possible, and I cannot find a way to improve the accuracy of this method. Is there a simpler/more accurate way to do this? Bonus for efficiency.

Comment: I think it's also flipped compared to the source. Try `Reverse`-ing your data at level 1, 2, or both?

Comment: @thorimur it is but I'm not worried about that

Answer (score 1):

My method seems to work, the only thing I needed to change is the color norm. Using `ColorDistance` improved the results significantly.

```
f[c_] := Module[{n},
  n = First@First@Position[colordata,#]&@First@MinimalBy[colordata,ColorDistance[RGBColor@c,RGBColor@#]&]-1;
  If[n==0, 0, 2.+5n/ncols]
]
```